# How do I migrate my Blogger blog to WordPress without losing my present search engine rank?

Tags: seo, wordpress, blogger

I presently own a Blogger blog which is already ranking on Google for some keywords. I want to migrate to WordPress because of low SEO quality of Blogger but I have some few concerns about the best way to go about it since I'm already ranking on Google.

Wouldn't that mean I'm going to be starting all over again? If I post the same post which I already posted to Blogger, wouldn't the new ones be ignored as duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how your site is setup. If you have your own domain on Blogger (i.e. `www.myblog.example`), the ranking should not change if you move to another provider. But if you have a blogger address, yes the ranking will drop because the adresse of the site will change.

Also, please note that the SEO is not made by Blogger (you cannot say "low SEO quality of Blogger..."). 95% of your SEO is coming from the quality of your content.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not easy, it is possible to completely move your blog to from blogger to Wordpress.
Wordpress even supports this in a way:
Once you install WP, go to Dashboard>Tools>Import>Blogger (see screenshot)[image]. This will import all your posts from blogger.
For further info on how to do this, [please refer to this article](https://firstsiteguide.com/move-blogger-to-wordpress/), which covers the topic in depth.